# Quando digito número quebrado, ele retira a vírgula e soma como número inteiro

Tags: c#, .net, formatação

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.Write("Digite sua primeira nota: ");
        double n1 = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.Write("Digite sua segunda nota: ");
        double n2 = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
        double resultado = (n1 + n2) / 2;
        Console.WriteLine("A Média é {0}", resultado);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Provavelmente precisa resolver a questão da cultura. De qualquer forma vários erros podem ocorrer na digitação. Se não puder converter corretamente não pode deixar fazer a conta.

```
using static System.Console;

public class Program {
    public static void Main(string[] args) {
        System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("pt-BR");
        Write("Digite sua primeira nota: ");
        double n1;
        if (!double.TryParse(ReadLine(), out n1)) {
            Write("nota digitada errada, estou encerrando, pode tentar novamente");
            return;
        }
        Write("Digite sua segunda nota: ");
        double n2;
        if (!double.TryParse(ReadLine(), out n2)) {
            Write("nota digitada errada, estou encerrando, pode tentar novamente");
            return;
        }
        WriteLine($"A Média é {(n1 + n2) / 2}");
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/y2ogn2). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/AjgRnK). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Console/PointComma.cs).

Answer (score 8):

A origem do problema é o seu regional Settings (do Windows), o meu computador é regional americano, usam ponto em casas decimais, sendo assim seu programa funciona usando pontos.

Você pode resolver forçando sua aplicação a usar

```
System.Globalization.CultureInfo
```

Porém sua aplicacão ficará fixa ao padrão que você definir, se você distribuir a mesma para outras regiões terá problemas.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Como faço para forçar a aplicação a usar `System.Globalozation.CultureInfo` em C#?

Comment: System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("pt-BR");  no início da sua aplicação