# A que o erro "Não é possível converter implicitamente tipo "void" em "int" " se refere?

Tags: c#

Meu objetivo é calcular porcentagem, ao tentar rodar o código abaixo recebo a mensagem de erro:

> "Não é possível converter implicitamente tipo `void` em `int`.

Como corrijo?

```
int var1 = Console.WriteLine("Insira bullshit");
int var2 = Console.WriteLine("Insira bullshit");
int Resultado = var1 / 100 * var2;

Console.ReadLine(); 
Console.WriteLine($"Resultado: {Resultado}");
```

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Dúvida Console.ReadLine](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/254477/d%c3%bavida-console-readline)

Answer (score 2):

O método [`WriteLine()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.writeline?view=net-8.0&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) tem como retorno `void`, ou seja retorna nada, então não tem valor na execução dele, e está tentando guardar um valor na variável, isto não é possível, precisa usar um método que retorne algum valor para poder guardar na variável, e no caso específico tem que ser um tipo `int`, por isso eu não poderia indicar o [`ReadLine()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.readline?view=net-8.0&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) também que retorna uma `string`.

Mas o que deseja parece ser que alguém digite algo, a pergunta não é clara quanto a isto e sem entender o problema fica complicado achar uma solução adequada, vou chutar que seja isto. Aí terá que usar o `ReadLine()` para pegar o dado digitado, convertê-lo para `int`de forma segura e então poderá usar no cálculo desejado, por sorte esse é um dos exercícios que as pessoas mais postam aqui e tem um monte de código que pode ver como é o certo.

Claro que só irá aprender se entender o que cada coisa faz, por isso seria bom fazer novas pesquisas sobre o assunto, aqui mesmo no site tem muita coisa, e se não tiver pode fazer uma nova perguntas mais específica.

Eu não vou colocar o código aqui porque não faz sentido colocar mais um exemplo de como usar o `ReadLine()` do jeito certo tem uma quantidade enorme de perguntas que isto já foi demonstrado e até tornaria a pergunta como duplicata se fosse por esse caminho:

- [Quando digito número quebrado, ele retira a vírgula e soma como número inteiro](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/236869/101)
- [Ler uma linha de console em C#](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/281432/101)
- [Entender "," como "." na hora de formatar](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/141112/101)
- [Por que a minha variável não altera o valor?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/393955/101)
- [Erro ao efetuar cálculo de média](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/288051/101)
- [Como faço pra receber um valor pra cada variável double no console?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/401756/101)
- [Erro ao comparar números e verificar se são iguais](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/136295/101)
- [Lendo informações do usuario](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/140106/101)
- [Como inverter um número positivo para negativo e vice versa no C#?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/406973/101)
- [Usando Console.ReadLine() no WriteLine()](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/254477/101)

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Mas, a pergunta é uma duplicata ... poderia sim ser fechada, é fechado aqui por menos que isso e inclusive o cara não está nem ai pra que foi respondido.

Comment: Se a pessoa não está nem aí pro que foi respondido eu não posso dizer que é inferir algo que eu não tenho controle e não tenho subsídio para tanto. Eu não acho que seja duplicata, se acha escolha uma e mande fechar. E não responda perguntas que você acha que é duplicata. Eu respondi no primeiro parágrafo o que realmente é o problema perguntado, depois eu coloquei outros pontos que se fosse o foco fariam duplicata. Lembrando que duplicata é algo que já tenha a resposta, e mostrar como fazer a verificação do dado de forma adequada quando usa o `ReadLine()`, é algo já respondido e seria duplicata

Comment: é duplicata sim, para de ser dessa forma e você sabe que é duplicata que o cara não tem nenhum tipo de conhecimento e C# e em programação é não está explicito, mas, sim implícito ... não precisa atacar ninguém e eu não te ataquei, só coloquei aquilo que realmente é. Se não fosse duplicata os links que você ligou na sua resposta não seria a resposta dessa pergunta.

Comment: Agora você está querendo incutir pensamento meu, isto não é legal. Eu não respondo baseado se a pessoa sabe ou não sabe algo, responde se a pergunta está feita de uma forma que dê para responder e dê para acrescentar algo útil ali. Eu não acho duplicata, inclusive a pergunta que você marcou não fala sobre o que foi pergunta e sim sobre o uso do `TryParse()`, que se fosse o caso seria duplicata, mas claramente a pergunta não fala sobre isto, é uma informação adicional.

Comment: Ok Maniero, você é assim e pronto.

Answer (score 2):

[Console.WriteLine](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.console.writeline?view=netframework-4.8) é para mostrar informações na tela em um programa `Console Application`, para pegar valores digitados na tela o comando é [Console.ReadLine](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.console.readline?view=netframework-4.8).

O seu código pode ser feito assim:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        decimal var1 = 0;
        decimal var2 = 0;
        if (decimal.TryParse(System.Console.ReadLine(), out var1) &&
            decimal.TryParse(System.Console.ReadLine(), out var2))
        {
            decimal Resultado = (var1 / 100) * var2;
            System.Console.WriteLine(var1);
            System.Console.WriteLine(var2);
            System.Console.WriteLine(Resultado);
        }
        else
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine("Error");
        }
    }
}
```

e quando se trabalha com divisão é melhor trabalhar com *tipo de dado* [decimal](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.decimal?view=netframework-4.8) porque uma divisão pode retornar valores com virgulas.

<sup>***Referencia:***</sup>

- [Console.WriteLine](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.console.writeline?view=netframework-4.8)
- [Console.ReadLine](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.console.readline?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: Eu não entendi o que "out" representa nesse código, poderia elucidar?

Comment: o `out` ele faz com que o argumento seja referencia [Leitura](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/out-parameter-modifier). Se o `TryParse` for um sucesso essa variável tem o valor do teste para você utilizar no seu código @Misaell